# probability: A' ∩ B' ∩ C and (A' ∩ B')U C

Tags: probability

how can I find the probability of the two events:

$P(A)=0.22, P(B)=0.25, P(C)=0.28, P(A ∩ B) =0.11 P(A ∩ C)=0.05 P(B ∩ C)=0.07 P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = 0.01$

1) $A' ∩ B' ∩ C $

I know that $A' ∩ B' = (A \cup B)' = 0.64$ (not sure if it helps tho)

2) $(A' ∩ B') \cup C$

any tips/solutions on how to go about questions like this? ty in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Venn Diagram]

Draw the Venn Diagram. It'll help.

P(A' ⋂ B' ⋂ C) = 0.17

P((A' ∩ B') U C) = 1 - 0.07 - 0.1 - 0.08 = 0.75

Comment: Start with the probability of A^B^C (purple region) and then using that calculate the probability of blue, light green and brown region and then calculate the probability of rest of the regions.

Comment: A'  is Yellow + Light Green + Red + Grey. (A' ∩ B') is Red + Grey. (A' ∩ B')U C is Red + Grey + Brown + Purple + Light Green. In other words, it is 1 - dark green - blue - yellow